# Facebook Group Invite from Website

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-group, facebook-invite

I have a password protected user area created and only want active users in my user area to know about a secret Facebook Group.  I provide support for the users of our software.

My question is how could I send an invite to join the Facebook user group automatically to the users email address (already provided during registration to my site) without having to go to Facebook and use the "Invite by Email" field.

Is this possible using PHP or other?

I am versed in PHP but have no idea how to get the hash code at the end of the Facebook invite.

Comment: Here is an example of the link that is sent.  It is user specific and has some form hash code.  Join CyberCafePro Support here: https://www.facebook.com/groupinvite/ATXoUtTwlAwKjLVxsTQwLZN6hUCSKEoj28NaXrmmuQzexDC-CbIFOoPZczoWxe6pylkywrUh0xniu5hvdKLgwmvgX6cxtZnuRMQEFje8lxqj97ozZByQvL17-hVp1T3bCOk_8tDJXPvwnRom66JsxypXRPo_a4pemzz3DZl2JHr7wmmxc87Jhsth-eyLAeK0IwoOcq11Y-9SjlqXSG64QkF3

Answer (score 0):

It's really simple there is a built-in function in php called [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php). As for how to get the users email, since it's provided at registeration you can use a `select` statement then send the emails using foreach loop. If you are still not sure how to start google : how to send an email using php.

Comment: I understand the PHP aspect of it.  What I do not know is how to get the Facebook link to send the user so it is valid to join the group.